# Devise Custom Sessions Controller weird thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to customise SessionsControllers, I've got One for the API part of my projet, the other one for websessions.

Here my routes.rb file

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'websessions'}
resource :dashboard

root :to => "dashboard#index"

namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "api/apisessions"}
end
```

It seems to work fine.

Now got a problem for my websessions_controller. I need to check a database flag (boolean) to check if my user is activated or not (FlgEnbl). Here my code

```
def create
resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:user][:email])
return failure unless resource

  if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])

    logger.info 'Flag value' => resource.FlgEnbl

    if resource.FlgEnbl == true

        sign_in('user', resource)
        redirect_to root_url

    else 
        return failure
    end
  else
    return failure
  end
end

protected

def failure
warden.custom_failure!
  return redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: 'Invalid email/password, or account disabled !'
end
```

So, if I try to log with a valid user and a wrong password, the failure message appear on my login page, valid user and password and bool set to true redirect to my dashboard page, but valid user and password with my bool set to false redirect to my dashboard page with a message 'You are already signed in.' instead of displaying the error message.

Same code with a render json on my api controller work.

Did I miss something or is it an issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found another solution adding this to  my model :

```
 def active_for_authentication? 
    super && FlgEnbl? 
  end 

  def inactive_message 
    if !FlgEnbl? 
      :not_approved 
    else 
      super # Use whatever other message 
    end 
  end
```

Just need to add the message for :not_approved in i118n devise file in failure section.

Hope this help.